# XP + Linux auto ssh proccess from WIN to LINUX 

Tags: linux, vbscript, windows-xp

Not sure if somewhere I can find what I want but I will ask it anyway -:)

I need to edit ordinary txt file every day on my PC XP windows (I use notepad file - file.txt)
And then I send this file VIA ssh (using reflection ftp client) to other Linux machine (as all know I need to enter login and password in the ftp client) ,
remark -  I can’t to edit the file.txt on the Linux machine because security issues

My target is to automate this procedure as the following process:

1. Edit the file.txt file and saved it on my PC
2. Send this file.txt automatically to the Linux machine without enter login/password by only one click – the target is to find some solution by add button to the file.txt file and by click on this button it will transfer the file automatically to the Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

To automate the SSH login, you have to generate pair of authentication keys (public/private) and you need to add the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the linux machine in the home dir of the user you're using to login with. I suggest you create a technical user, that will have minimal rights (like writing only to the desired directory where you have to copy the file to).

To automate the sending part, you will probably have to write a script that will issue the ssh command to the linux machine. For this purpose you need to setup a tool that supports ssh from the console. Take a look at [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [sshwindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/). That's how I would do it. There could be a better approach, I am not very familiar with Windows.

P.S. [This article](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2329.html) you may find useful. It presents different Windows specific approach.